# What is the meaning of error LNK2019

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2019

Can Somebody tell me what does the following error implies?

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: class
>   TLst & __thiscall
>   TLst::operator=(class
>   TLst const &)"
>   (??4?$TLst@VTInt@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void
>   __thiscall TPair >::GetVal(class TInt
>   &,class TLst &)const "
>   (?GetVal@?$TPair@VTInt@@V?$TLst@VTInt@@@@@@QBEXAAVTInt@@AAV?$TLst@VTInt@@@@@Z)    randomgraph.obj randomgraph

Comment: What language? C++? It's a linker error.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it means that the linker sees a reference to a symbol, but it can't find it anywhere - often due to a missing library or object file.

In *this case* this happened because you implemented your templated class'es member functions in a .cpp file - they should be implemented in the header.

A template class is a **template** not a class. When the compiler see you using e.g. `vector<int> f;` it creates a new class `vector<int>` from the template `vector`. In order to create e.g. `vector<int>::size()` it needs to see the implementation of `size()` at the point where the template is instantiated - and it can't do that if the implementation of `size()` isn't in the header file.

You can get around this by explicitly instantiating `vector` for `int` - Then the compiler will see the explicit instantiation when it compiles the cpp file. This defeats the purpose of having a template - it'd only be usable for the types you predefine with explicit instantiation. So, short story, always fully implement templates in header files.

Comment: The template class defined in header file is TVec <TPair <TInt, TLst<TInt> >  > and the template <class TVal> class TVec { public: typedef TVal* TIter; And in the .cpp file, the linker error is coming for the line:  for (TNdClss::TIter CI = ndClss.BegI(); CI<ndClss.EndI(); CI++) {
  fprintf(OutF_ClsswNIds,"%d --> ", CI->Val1);       where typedef TVec<TPair <TInt, TLst<TInt> > > TNdClss; is defined in header.

Comment: Where's `TLst & TLst::operator=` implemented?

Answer (score 1):

`Unresolved external symbol` means that there's a reference that the linker can't find. It's usually caused by forgetting to add an object file or library to the link step. (Including the header file for a class isn't enough - you also have to add the implementation code.)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. In the template class TLst, the function

TLst TLst::operator=(const TLst&);

was declared but it was not defined.

I had to define the function in my .cpp file. I could have defined it in my header file as well.

Thanks for the replies.

Somnath